# como obtener los datos que se estran mostrando en DataTables?

Tags: jquery, datatables

Que tal buen dia lo que estoy tratando de lograr es que me devuelva un array con los datos que se estan mostrando en pantalla, por ejemplo tengo un listado de 300 filas, pero solo estoy mostrando por default 10 en una pagina, quisera poder obtener ese listado para el consumo de web service, y si le da a mostrar 25 quisiera poder obtener ese listado o si es buscado y solo le devuelve un resultado

gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La instancia de DataTables [tiene un método data](https://datatables.net/reference/api/data()) para recuperar el contenido. Dependiendo de cómo lo estés trayendo imagino que su formato se mantiene (array de arrays o array de objetos, me refiero).

```
const table = $('#example').DataTable();
 
console.log({data: table.data()});
```

Si quieres obtener solamente una parte, entonces debieras [usar el método rows](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().data()) primero para preseleccionar ciertas filas. Ese método te devuelve la misma instancia con la operación aplicada (preselección, o filtro, orden, etc), luego puedes invocar el método `data`

```
const table = $('#example').DataTable(),
      table_filtered=table.rows({page:'current'})
 
console.log({data: table_filtered.data()});
```

(Si llenas la tabla con ajax debes esperar que refresque los datos, o sino tendrás un arreglo vacío)

Comment: olle amigo muchas gracias es exactamente lo que necesitaba, imagino que si solo quiero los datos de la primera columna deberia cambiar por column u obtenerlos con  ese metodo de Datatables

Comment: Supongo que puedes aplicar `table.columns({page:'current'}).data()` y si no, combinar el filtro sobre rows y luego invocar columns sobre la instancia prefiltrada